# Dynamically setting value of a h:selectOneMenu using c:forEach

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jstl

I'm working on a project that requires me to display and be able to select and store tags to the product. Tags are provided in tree-like structure. I can't assume maximum depth of a tags tree.

I wanted to display tags split by levels, using c:forEach - p:selectManyCheckbox - f:selectItems, and handling selections using p:ajax components.

I use following types to store possible values and selections in Tree object:

```
HashMap<Long, ArrayList<Tag>> tree;
HashMap<Long, Object[]> selected;
```

Hashmap keys are equal to "tag level".

In order to display values I use following code for testing:

```
<p:panelGrid id="tagDisplay" columns="2">
    <c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="idx">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{idx}"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{product.tags.selected[1]}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{product.tags.tree[1]}" var="tag" itemLabel="#{tag.name}" itemValue="#{tag.id}" />
            <p:ajax listener="#{product.selectorListener}" update="tagDisplay" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    </c:forEach>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Code seemed to work fine, though displayed five times.

Now I'm stuck trying to dynamically bind Hashmaps to selectors. As I replaced "1" with "idx", I got no results.

I tried to use ui-repeat with a dummy table, but then I lost panelgrid structure.

Any help will be appreciated!

My environment - Websphere 8.5, JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<c:forEach begin end>` is only for static iteration, not for dynamic iteration.

You'd better iterate over `#{product.tags.tree}` itself in `<c:forEach items>`. Each iteration over a `Map` will give `Map.Entry` back which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

```
<p:panelGrid ...>
    <c:forEach items="#{product.tags.tree}" var="entry" varStatus="loop">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{loop.index}"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{product.tags.selected[entry.key]}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{entry.value}" ... />
            ...
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    </c:forEach>
</p:panelGrid>
```

That said, must it really be a `HashMap`? Don't you rather want a fixed ordered `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: Hmm, iteration idea seems solid, thanks! So I should use LinkedHashMap to retain iteration order.
Do i get it right?

Comment: To retain insertion order. Otherwise the ordering is basically dependent on JVM make/version.

Comment: Oj, I will check that one out, thanks for your support as always :D